# Bootstrap CSS file not connecting to HTML file in VS Code

Tags: html

I am trying to connect the Bootstrap CSS and HTML files in Visual Studio, but they are not connecting. Does anyone know why? It is probably something very easy that I am missing, but when I run the code in my browser, the CSS is not there. You can see the link to the stylesheet below. The names of the files are index.html and cover.css. This is the Cover example in Bootstrap, and I am trying to run it using VS Code.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.82.0">
    <title>Cover Template · Bootstrap v5.0</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/cover/">

    

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="../assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>

    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="cover.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body class="d-flex h-100 text-center text-white bg-dark">
    
<div class="cover-container d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
  <header class="mb-auto">
    <div>
      <h3 class="float-md-start mb-0">Cover</h3>
      <nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center float-md-end">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main class="px-3">
    <h1>Cover your page.</h1>
    <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>
    <p class="lead">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary fw-bold border-white bg-white">Learn more</a>
    </p>
  </main>

  <footer class="mt-auto text-white-50">
    <p>Cover template for <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/" class="text-white">Bootstrap</a>, by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo" class="text-white">@mdo</a>.</p>
  </footer>
</div>


    
  </body>
</html>


CSS: 

/*
 * Globals
 */


/* Custom default button */
.btn-secondary,
.btn-secondary:hover,
.btn-secondary:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none; /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
}


/*
 * Base structure
 */

body {
  text-shadow: 0 .05rem .1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.cover-container {
  max-width: 42em;
}


/*
 * Header
 */

.nav-masthead .nav-link {
  padding: .25rem 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: .25rem solid transparent;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link + .nav-link {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-masthead .active {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Likely you just got the URL wrong. What does the Network tab in your browser's developer tools show when you look at it?

Answer (score -2):

Check whether you add all the `js`and `css`file og Bootstrap cover

check whether you added your `js` at end of html

check the `page source` of bootstrap cover website for full source code

steps
 1. go to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/cover/ 
2. Right click and click `view page source`

compare the full code with your code